# Charset error, php smarty mysql

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, smarty

I've recently come across a weird problem about the meta charset.

If I don't set any charset in my header, all accent like é,è,à.. are show correctly (even var from php) except for text comming from my database are replace by a little question marks in a lozenge.

If I set one of those(I tried both of them) charset in my header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="iso-8859-15" />
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Text from my database is okay, but all the rest show the little question marks instead of the accent.

My database character set is UTF-8 unicode, and Collation is UTF_8 general_ci.

Note that I'm using smarty, but I did'nt change the charset in config cause his default is UTF-8.

Comment: Could you please add the HTTP charset headers, your server is sending. Meta tags in HTML are only one source for a browser to determine the charset of a website. The HTTP headers are another.

Comment: The character you're talking about represents an invalid UTF-8 character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found a solution, I'm using an ORM, and i only add the charset=utf8 in the setConnection method like this

```
$config->set_connections(array(
    'development' => 'mysql://user:pass@localhost/mydb;charset=utf8')
);
```